# hive julian date conversion

Tags: hiveql, julian-date

I am trying to convert Julian date in HIVE, for example 0167017 to calendar date. My example should covert to 1967-01-17 (01 should become 19, 67 considered as year 67 and 017 as 17 days in the year. What hive date format should I use to achieve this?

I tried this format, but didn't work. select 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('0167121','CCYYDDD')) ;

Answer (score 0):

If 01 should become 19 then 02 =20 and so on, right? Then convert 01 to 19, concatenate it with rest of the string and apply yyyyDDD format:

```
hive> select  to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(18+cast(substr('0167017',1,2)as int),substr('0167017',3)),'yyyyDDD')));
OK
1967-01-17
Time taken: 0.07 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Use  `to_date()` or `substr` to remove '00:00:00' if necessary

Comment: i was able to do it using this approach. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ibh If you are satisfied with my answer then please accept or vote